# What is the minimum level to join a party?

Tags: neverwinter

Whenever I try to invite a friend to a party, it tells me they are too low level. What level do they need to be before we can party up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you arrive to Protector Enclave, you can join/make a party. Before of that you can play with other people but you can't make a party since you are playing the prologue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug.  I have a level 38 that is 'too low a level' to party with my brother - also 38